# read value from registry via batch file

Tags: batch-file

in my batch file I need to check the version of the oracle that install on the machine.
I want to read the oracl_home that the machine contains.
I have a path in registry like:
KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\zdf\oracle
and I want to read the attributs name under oracle.
how can I do it????
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think that you miss "H" in  "KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE".
2. use reg query:

   `reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\zdf\oracle" /s`

the `/s` queries all subkeys and values recursively

Comment: can you write me the full command for it??I want a list of the childern of the key:oracle

Comment: these command give me all the output.these output include children that I dont need.I want only the children that contains oracle_home in properties how I filter it?

Comment: you need to assign the output of this command to a variable after comparing to a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose oracle is 10.0 under your registry path

```
@echo off
regedit /e C$D$L$A$.bxt "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\your\regisgry\path"
echo "set" > C$D$L$A$.bat
find "oracle" <C$D$L$A$.bxt >>C$D$L$A$.bat
```